# Using Shopware 6 can you display the configurator on the category overview page?

Tags: plugins, twig, e-commerce, shopware

I am using Shopware 6 and have a plugin installed that create a quickbuy lightbox popup. Works fine, but doesnt pull in my dropdowns (configurator) for my product variables. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible by default to show variants within the listing within the current version 6.2. You would need a plugin to archive this functionality.